# Meteor, how to pass callback and error to caller method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

In my Meteor.methods I have

```
var post= Posts.insert({...},  function(err,docsInserted){
  Posts.update({...} , {...});
});
```

I want to create an insert model as suggested by David Weldon [here](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/models). 
My model looks like this:

```
_.extend(Posts, {
    ins:function (docID){
      return  Posts.insert({...});
    }
});
```

In my methods I have this:

```
var post= Posts.ins(docID,  function(err,docsInserted){
  Posts.update({...} , {...});
});
```

How can I use a callback and error handling in the method? I'd like to be able to execute code when the Post is inserted successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [collection.insert](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert):

> Insert a document in the collection. Returns its unique _id.
>
> Arguments
>
> doc Object
>
> The document to insert. May not yet have an _id attribute, in which case Meteor will generate one for you.
>
> callback Function
>
> Optional. If present, called with an error object as the first argument and, if no error, the _id as the second.

As I understand it, you want to execute a callback function if `ins` executes successfully. Given that information, here's how I'd structure the code:

```
_.extend(Posts, {
    ins:function (docID, callback){
      Posts.insert({...}, function( error, id ) {
          if( error ) {
            callback( error, null );
          } else {
            callback( null, id );
          }
      });
    }
});
```

You don't actually need to return anything.  You can just execute the callback function and pass parameters along appropriately. Then you can call the function with the following code:

```
Posts.ins(docID,  function(err,docsInserted){
  if( error ) {
    // Handle error.
  } else {
    Posts.update({...} , {...});
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the great response. another question, is the new model method (ins) is going to be executable from client site?

Comment: That depends on where you defined it. As long as you didn't define it in your `server` folder, then it should be.

Comment: so how can I deny access from client side?

Comment: If you have the `insecure` package removed, calling it client-side will fail.  If not, you'll have to use allow/deny rules.